# Batch to run multiple telnets

Tags: batch-file, telnet

I am new to batch files and was wanting to build a file to execute a telnet session to the same ip address multiple times (possibly 50 then moving up). We have some equipment in the field that gets in a low memory state and can be forced to reboot with several telnet sessions. I would like to be prompted for the ip address and then a numerical value of how many telnet sessions to launch then it execute. Running win10. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to perform a denail of service (DOS) attack. It would be better to create a scheduled task to monitor the memory within the system and trigger a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
@Echo off

set /p "$IP=Enter the IP : "
set /p "$N=Enter the number of Iteration : "

for /l %%a in (1,1,%$N%) do start telnet %$IP%
```

Comment: When I do this it is placing my IP in brackets (telnet [x.x.x.x]), this will not work in windows telnet. When I remove the brackets I get this:Enter the IP : 10.129.20.2
Enter the number of Iteration : 1
Your telnet command with IP 10.129.20.2 Iteration : [1]

Comment: I just putted this line as an example replace the line after the `do` with the right Telnet command using `%$ip%` you don't need `%%a` at all.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I still can't make this work as desired. To be more specific I need multiple cmd screens to open based on the number of iterations. So if ip = x.x.x.x iteration = 10 I need 10 separate cmd telnet sessions to the specified IP. Is this achievable?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe this will do the trick. I am waiting on a chance to hammer a blade with telnet sessions to force a reboot. Thanks again

Comment: The telnet sessions are launching and closing so fast I can't see what is happening. I believe the ip address is still not in the right format. It just needs to be telnet x.x.x.x

Comment: telnet [-a][-e escape char][-f log file][-l user][-t term][host [port]]                         this is what is being returned

Comment: I don't know what telnet command you need ! I just show you how to run them.